# Payment failed action notification placement

Tags: payment, dynamic-ui

Basically I work for a delivery company named REDX, where they delivery parcels door to door. We have a dashboard as shown below, and now we will introduce a feature to let the user know that the payment has been bounced… we already have a global message shown at top, and toast message on top centre position… I created few variations to show how we can solve this solution… Note: there can be multiple actions at any given point and the situation being here the payment is bounced therefore the user need to update the payment method… need you opinion on the variations below and if there is a better one can you please suggest… thanks and waiting for your reply.

A. Can have multiple actions + notification and is autoscrollable with 5 sec interval and user will also have the ability to navigate on their own

B. Takes up screen space, and the actionable notices are stacked and can be open and close to see all at a particular time

C. Slides in and auto scrollable and the user have the ability to click on close icon to dismiss it[image: One screen shot showing each of the three options described]

Answer (score 1):

Good topic, a common consideration for saas products and portals.

I would say straight up that C isn't an option. Chat bot style pop ups are a nuisance and I believe users close and forget about these asap. I would suggest the first two options are more clear, front and centre and at the top so sequentially the user will see them each time and be reminded.

For A and B, I would not include this message in a reel where it can be superceded by other messages. It's about the user's right to use the service which means it is of high importance. It should be a message of its own.

Considering the issue posed to the user, how destructive is it to disregard the message, and for how long can they do so without repurcussion?
All paid services like this have their own period of time they will run without payment, or in fact, how long before the payment is finally due before service termination.

Based on that, how important then is it that the user acts on this message? That would help inform the boldness, placement and interaction level of the message.

Example: If the user has a week to resolve the issue and pay before services are affected, I would see value in option A. Once 7 days has passed, I would find it acceptable to cover the whole page in an iframe that is red, obvious and has one cta, to rectify the payment issue.
That at least is an option I would review, see how the business' legal or payments team feel about it, and if you have the ability to run UR, what the potential users say.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view variation B is the best. This action has critical affect on customer satisfaction because if he missed this message he will not get a service thus he will be unsatisfied by your company regardless the fact that this is his fault.

Personally I would strengthen even more means to catch customers attantion:

- Highlight even more important action section.
- Use bell symbol or another special mark at top menu section.
- Make special card in Overview Payment Summary say Bounced Amount using red background and white text.

Of course, this bounced amount may be not so critical so could be depicted more softly.